# Express.js response is not defined error

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to implement a simple login, but there's a small issue.
`bcrypt` returns a `response`, so when I try to `res.send("stuff")`, it returns an error since it thinks that I'm trying to access a property of the res object rather than express.js's response feature. (correct me if I'm wrong).

> ReferenceError: response is not defined at authController.js:79:21

```
exports.loginModalPost = function (req, res) {
    // post
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

    // email & password validation.
    user.where('email', email).fetch().then(function (data) {
        if (data) {
            data = data.toJSON();
            bcrypt.compare(password, data.password_hash, function (err, res) {
                if(res === true) {
                    res.send("login is valid");
                } else {
                    // return err, but don't say that password is wrong to the end user.
                    res.send("password is wrong");
                }
            });
        } else {
            // email is wrong, no need to check password.
            // return err, but don't say that email is wrong.
            res.send("email is wrong");
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second argument `res` in `compare` method's callback, conflict with express's response object `res`, you can't declare same variable name in one scope.

just update your code like below:

```
bcrypt.compare(password, data.password_hash, function (err, result) {
                if(result === true) {
                    res.send("login is valid");
                } else {
                    // return err, but don't say that password is wrong to the end user.
                    res.send("password is wrong");
                }
            });
```